# TFS, subst, Visual Studio 2010, relative paths

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, source-control-bindings, subst

My TFS workspace is at `C:\Users\...\MyProject`, which I have mapped to `X:\` using Windows subst command. In my Visual Studio 2010 solutions, this works fine for most of the projects. Only 2 of them are always linked (absolutely!) wo the `C:\Users\...` path, no matter what I do.

I tried:

1. Removing and re-adding them, obviously.
2. Removing the explicit absolute mapping for those 2 projects in my workspace settings. It is re-created as soon as I add the projects.
3. Manually twiddling in the solution file with Notepad. Makes the source control binding invalid, and 2.'s explicit bindings are re-created when I rebind them.

Some help would be very cool. I'm stuck for several hours only dealing with source control...

Cheers
Matthias

P.S. Some might wonder why I do the `subst`stuff: As the project directory names are pretty long, the often exceed 260 characters, which makes many features in the VS/.NET environment stop working.

Comment: Why don't you just place your code then in c:\src?

Comment: Well, meanwhile I did, and it works. Nevertheless, the behavior confuses me: As I re-created the workspace and opened the solution, VS checked out each project and changed the references to relative paths. No idea what those paths are driven by...